# Плавное отображение изображений в списке

Tags: android, lazyloading, universal-image-loader

К примеру есть список, в котором у item-ов есть текстовые поля и n-ое количество картинок. Что я делаю:

1) Использую библиотеку `ImageLoader`

В `Application`-классе, я его инициализирую следующим образом

```
public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(null)
                .cacheInMemory(false)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.place_holder_view_white)
                .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
                .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
```

Где `.showStubImage(R.drawable.place_holder_view_white)` подкладывает картинку-заглушку до появления прогруженной пикчи. Это просто белая png-шка, с конкретными размерами. В проекте она одна.

2) В адаптере вызываю метод загрузки, который представляет из себя:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("drawable://" + R.drawable.icon_image_holder, imageView);
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "alpha", 0, 1).setDuration(400).start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "alpha", 0, 1).setDuration(400).start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

            }

        });
```

Здесь видно, что если картинка не прогрузилась, то она заменяется на другую, взятую из проекта. А если загрузилась - то плавно отображается на месте заглушки, через aplha анимацию.

Всё работает прекрасно, но! только если все картинки имеют одинаковые размеры, совпадающие с размерами картинки-заглушки. В противном же случае, список начинает дергаться. 
Как же сделать так, чтобы imageHolder автоматически подстраивался под будущие размеры вставляемой картинки?

Comment: Ну либо заранее надо знать размеры будущей картинки и заглушки вставлять с scaleType необходимым (centerCrop например), либо задать размеры картинки по размеру заглушки (т.е. без wrap_content) и тоже scaleType'ом вписывать загруженные картинки...

Comment: Согласен, но по мне первое решение нереальное/громоздкое, а вот второе вполне приемлимо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так, чтоб ImageLoader подгонял размер загружаемой картинки в препроцессоре.

Создаем свой BitmapProcessor

```
 class MyBitmapProcessor implements BitmapProcessor{

        private int maxSize;

        private MyBitmapProcessor(){}

        public MyBitmapProcessor(int size){
            maxSize = size;
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap process(Bitmap bitmap) {
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();

            if (width > height) {
                float ratio = (float) width / maxSize;
                width = maxSize;
                height = (int) (height / ratio);
            } else if (height > width) {
                float ratio = (float) height / maxSize;
                height = maxSize;
                width = (int) (width / ratio);
            } else {
                height = maxSize;
                width = maxSize;
            }
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
        }
    }
```

и сетим его в опции лоадера

```
 MyBitmapProcessor bitmapProcessor = new MyBitmapProcessor(200);
 new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
   .preProcessor(bitmapProcessor)
 ...
```

Так же можно попробовать использовать дисплеер с анимацией

```
  new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
      .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
 ...
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, мне размеры заведомо не известны.